Add a watermark during printjob by C++
I'm working on a C++ application and need to add a watermark to documents during the printing process. Specifically, I want to intercept the print job, add a watermark, and then proceed with printing.  Here’s the scenario: When a user presses Ctrl + P, the Print dialog appears. The user selects the printer and clicks Print. At this point, the print job is sent to the printer.  I’ve tried the following approaches:  Using PrintDocument Class: I attempted to use the PrintDocument class to handle printing and add a watermark, but this only works if I generate the document within the application, not if I’m printing an existing document.  What I’m looking to achieve is:  Intercepting the Print Job: Pause or capture the print job right after it’s initiated by the user. Adding a Watermark: Modify the document content to include a watermark. Continuing with Printing: Resume the printing process with the watermark applied.
is there a windows API can i achieve this? and this is my code to create a watermark on the screen :
HWND CreateWatermarkWindows(HINSTANCE hInstance, RECT screenRect) {
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowExW(
        WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, // Add WS_EX_TRANSPARENT here
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_POPUP,
        screenRect.left,
        screenRect.top,
        screenRect.right - screenRect.left,
        screenRect.bottom - screenRect.top,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        hInstance,
        nullptr
    );
    // Set layered window attributes with black background and opacity
    BYTE alpha = static_cast<BYTE>(OpacityLevel * 255); // Compute opacity
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(0, 0, 0), alpha, LWA_COLORKEY | LWA_ALPHA);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    windows.push_back(hWnd);
    return hWnd;
}


Your best bet is to create a printer driver which, if selected in the print dialog, will modify  at driver level the input and pass it through to an actual driver. In short, don't. What are you trying to achieve anyway? This is too complex to be solved here.

@MichaelChourdakis
i want achieve is add a watermark to the content you want to print.

What is the original problem you need to solve? Why do you need to add this watermark? What is the underlying problem that is supposed to solve? What is your actual assignment? What are your requirement? What are your limitations?

And have you checked to see if the printer driver doesn't already have a function to add a watermark? Many seem to have such a functionality. Perhaps it's possible to get the driver, set that option, and then continue with its printing?

@Someprogrammerdude I’m developing a solution to protect sensitive information by adding watermarks to printed documents. The idea is to include the computer user’s name as a watermark to identify who printed the documents. Currently, my application adds a watermark to the screen to prevent screen capture leaks. I want to extend this functionality to also add watermarks directly to printed content to enhance security and prevent unauthorized use.

@Someprogrammerdude
I have checked the printer drivers and confirmed that they do not offer a feature to add a watermark to printed content.

The easiest way might be to have the user print the document through your app.

@MichaelChourdakis
No, I don’t want the user to print the document through my application. I want to handle all printing methods in Windows.

@GhaithSaaa hacking the printing mechanism would require (except luck) a kernel mode driver. If you are willing to invest in that, start by learning KMDF (personally I think it's futile for such a job but whatever). If a user-mode app tries to conceal anything, a user that is just above than a newbie would be able to bypass it if it wants badly that information. Is what you want to do worth it?

@MichaelChourdakis
After researching this area, I discovered that some companies have implemented this feature as an application rather than as a driver. This is what I aim to achieve.

@MichaelChourdakis
Is it really possible that there is no Windows API available to modify the content of print jobs and add a watermark to it? Or is there any other method, not necessarily a Windows API, that could achieve this?

@MichaelChourdakis help me please LOL

I'm hintless, I would do it the way I told you, I would force the users to print from my app.
